# EC2 Amazon web server not answering by ssh connection. (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: linux, symfony, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a site hosted by an Amazon Web Server and I use a ssh connection to access it.

Suddenly the server stopped answering (I was deleting caches of some symfony2 applications as I do frequently).

First it told me:
    ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

And now it's not answering at all (not by ssh neither by the website)

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com [xxxxxxxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/xxxx/.ssh/xxxxxx.pem" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxx/.ssh/xxxxx.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxx.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

What can it be?

This problem happened before, and after some hours it stopped.
Can it be a RAM problem? I am thinking that maybe some action I did in the server may have blocked him (just like a normal computer that is being too much requested).

Comment: Are you connection through a new network/public network?

Comment: @barbrac yes, I am using a public network I guess

Comment: Potentially, public networks can block port access used by SSH, however if you've connected via this network before then this shouldn't be a problem.